# modiagram and p/sigma orbitals

Tags: modiagram

I'm using the `modiagram` package and I'm half-way
through a text (so I'm eager to get this to work). Now I'm up to
filling up p orbitals and hence the σ(pz) orbitals. I'm taught
that the *z* axis is the bonding axis and that it is the p(z)
orbitals that form the molecular sigma orbitals. `modiagram` assumed
the *x* axis and p(x) orbitals. Is it possible to configuration or
hack `modiagram` to have this suite my needs?

Also, is it possible to change the format of the labels from
2σ(x) to σ(2px)? Should this perhaps be a question on
it's own?

I have actually read the code, but it's all new to me. I'd be glad for
any kind of answer, be it hints on where to hack the `.sty`file or
hints about the package.

Reading the code, I understand that it is around line 1150 I should
focus for both problems but the code is all new to me and I'm
embarrassed to say I don't understand it.

Here's a MWE on top of things.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{mhchem}
\usepackage{modiagram}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
  \begin{MOdiagram}[names,labels,labels-fs=\footnotesize]
    \atom[\ce{C}]{left}{ 2s, 2p = {; up, up} }
    \atom[\ce{C}]{right}{ 2s, 2p = {; up, up} }
    \molecule[\ce{C2}]{ 2sMO, 2pMO = {; pair, pair} }
    \EnergyAxis[title=$E$]
  \end{MOdiagram}
\end{center}

N.B. Wouldn't it be great to have the $\sigma$ orbital be formatted
$\sigma_{2pz}$ or $\sigma_{2p_z}$ and the $\pi$ orbital $\pi_{2py}$ or
$\pi_{2p_y}$.

\end{document}
```

Comment: @clemens And a final thing: what are px, py and pz AOs named?

Comment: You mean the node names? The available ones are shown in the figure in section 3.3 (the naming scheme)

Comment: @clemens Sure they are. Sorry for being so sloppy. Thanks for the immediate help. How kind. Cheers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks again for the feedback Clemens. Here are two examples of me
using the `\AO` command which made it possible to customize the use
`modiagram` and solve my problems.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{modiagram}
\usepackage[version=3]{mhchem}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
  \begin{MOdiagram}[names,labels,labels-fs=\footnotesize]
    % left atom
    \AO[2sleft](1cm){s}[label={$2s_{2}$}]{1;pair} %AO1
    \AO[2pxleft](1.5cm){s}[label={$2p_x$}]{5;pair}
    \AO[2pyleft](2cm){s}[label={$2p_y$}]{5;up}
    \AO[2pzleft](1cm){s}[label={$2p_z$}]{5;up}    
    \node at (1cm, -1){\ce{O}};

    % right atom
    \AO[2sright](7cm){s}[label={$2s$}]{1;pair} % AO3
    \AO[2pxright](6.5cm){s}[label={$2p_x$}]{5;pair}
    \AO[2pyright](7cm){s}[label={$2p_y$}]{5;up}
    \AO[2pzright](7.5cm){s}[label={$2p_z$}]{5;up}
    \node at (7cm, -1){\ce{O}};

    % molecule
    \AO[sigma2](4.5cm){s}[label={$\sigma_{2s}$}]{0.5;pair} % AO5
    \AO[sigma2*](4.5cm){s}[label={$\sigma^*_{2s}$}]{1.5;pair}
    \AO[pi2x](4.2cm){s}[label={$\pi_{2p_x}$}]{4;pair} % AO7
    \AO[pi2y](4.8cm){s}[label={$\pi_{2p_y}$}]{4;pair}
    \AO[sigma2pz](4.5cm){s}[label={$\sigma_{2p_z}$}]{3;pair}

    \AO[pi2x*](4.2cm){s}[label={$\pi^*_{2p_x}$}]{7;up} % AO10
    \AO[pi2y*](4.8cm){s}[label={$\pi^*_{2p_y}$}]{7;up}
    \AO[sigma2pz*](4.5cm){s}[label={$\sigma^*_{2p_z}$}]{8;}
    \node at (4.5cm, -1){\ce{O2}};

    \draw[densely dotted,draw=black] (2sleft.0) -- (sigma2.180);
    \draw[densely dotted,draw=black] (2sleft.0) -- (sigma2*.180);
    \draw[densely dotted,draw=black] (2sright.180) -- (sigma2.0);
    \draw[densely dotted,draw=black] (2sright.180) -- (sigma2*.0);

    \draw[densely dotted,draw=black] (2pyleft.0) -- (pi2x.180);
    \draw[densely dotted,draw=black] (2pxright.180) -- (pi2y.0);
    \draw[densely dotted,draw=black] (2pyleft.0) -- (pi2x*.180);
    \draw[densely dotted,draw=black] (2pxright.180) -- (pi2y*.0);

    \draw[densely dotted,draw=black] (2pzleft.0) -- (sigma2pz*.180);
    \draw[densely dotted,draw=black] (2pzleft.0) -- (sigma2pz.180);
    \draw[densely dotted,draw=black] (2pzright.180) -- (sigma2pz*.0);
    \draw[densely dotted,draw=black] (2pzright.180) -- (sigma2pz.0);
    \EnergyAxis[title=$E$]
  \end{MOdiagram}
\end{center}


\begin{center}
  \begin{MOdiagram}[names,labels,labels-fs=\footnotesize]
    % left atom
    \AO[2sleft](1cm){s}[label={$2s_{2}$}]{.5;pair} %AO1
    \AO[2pxleft](1.5cm){s}[label={$2p_x$}]{3;up}
    \AO[2pyleft](2cm){s}[label={$2p_y$}]{3;up}
    \AO[2pzleft](1cm){s}[label={$2p_z$}]{3;}    
    \node at (1cm, -1){\ce{C}};
    \node[align=center,text width=2cm] at (1cm, -1.5cm){four valence $e^-$};

    % right atom
    \AO[2sp31](5.7cm){s}[label={$2sp^3$}]{2;up} % AO3
    \AO[2sp32](6.4cm){s}[label={$2sp^3$}]{2;up}
    \AO[2sp33](7.1cm){s}[label={$2sp^3$}]{2;up}
    \AO[2sp34](7.8cm){s}[label={$2sp^3$}]{2;up}
    \node at (7cm, -1.5cm){\itshape Hybrid orbitals};

    \draw[ultra thick,->](3cm, 1cm) -- (5cm, 1cm)
      node[midway,below]{\scriptsize\itshape hybridization};
    \EnergyAxis[title=$E$]
  \end{MOdiagram}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```